# How to automatically re-establish connections after DB server restart (in jboss 6.4.0)

Tags: jboss, datasource, jboss6.x

Looking for valid data-source configuration to re-establish connection pool after DB server restart(without jboss restart).

**Thank you in advance.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the following settings enabled in your JBoss datasource to recover from a DB server restart:

```
1. <validate-on-match> or <background-validation>.
2. <valid-connection-checker> or <check-valid-connection-sql>
3. <exception-sorter>
```

You can read about how to configure these in this [link](http://www.ironjacamar.org/doc/userguide/1.1/en-US/html_single/index.html#deployingds_descriptor) table 5-19 and section 5.3.2 .